# How to fix incorrect decimal places of a multiplication result

Tags: python, string, floating-point, decimal

I'm having a problem with the following calculation:

```
>>> print(float('32.31') * 1e9)
32310000000.000004
```

I need this result to be `32310000000.0` (without the false decimal place). This also occurs when using a float directly:

```
>>> print(32.31 * 1e9)
32310000000.000004
```

Is there a way to avoid the false decimal place? Analysing the string and rounding to the number of decimal places is not a pefered solution.

Many thanks in advance.

NOTE: The following works fine:

```
>>> print(32.32 * 1e9)
32320000000.0
```

so I'm really happy I found the problem above during testing.

EDIT: Thank you for your quick answers! Sorry, I've missed an important point. The method must also work for when the result is less than one, e.g.:

```
32.31 * 1e-9
```

...in this case I cannot use `round(32.31 * 1e-9, 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to avoid your problem is to use the `decimal` module, which works in base ten and thus works the way humans would work (if we were much faster).

```
from decimal import Decimal
value = float(Decimal('32.31') * Decimal(1e9))
```

This yields the value you want,

```
32310000000.0
```

Another way is to use the `fractions` module, which works with exact values:

```
from fractions import Fraction
value = float(Fraction('32.31') * Fraction(1e9))
```

Note that in both of these methods, we must convert `1e9` and not just the decimal value. Using `1e9` as a float converts the intermediate values to float and the approximation problem pops up again. In either method, you could leave off the final conversion to float type and just continue to work with a `Decimal` or `Fraction` value. Either of these methods is somewhat slower than using float types: you gain accuracy at the expense of speed. That speed decrease may matter in some situations.

---

Regarding your edit to your question: using the value `1e-9` in either of my methods will still result in what you want, namely the value `3.231e-08`.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) The `Fraction` method fixes my problem and all my unit tests pass!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in printing with a single decimal place, you can use [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) by specifying the number after decimal you want to have, in this case 1

```
print(round(float('32.31') * 1e9, 1))
# 32310000000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the representation limitation of the floats's binary mantissa. 32.31 cannot be represented by a division by a power of two.   If you know your values will always be integers (or a known number of decimal places), you can use `round()` or `int(round())` to circumvent the limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're using Python 3.

If you only care about the result being printed, use string formatting:

```
print("{r:1.2f}".format(r=32.31 * 1e9))
```

Another way to do it is using the older formatting syntax:

```
print("%1.1f" % (32 * 1e9))
```

I prefer the first, but either will work.